# Windows 2016 Server Core - Add node to a SQL Server Failover Cluster (NOT Working)

Tags: sql-server, failovercluster, windows-server-core

2016 Server CORE.
Add node to SQL server 2019 Failover Cluster.

Steps were taken:
Added the server to the Failover Cluster

I found this page, [Install SQL Server from the Command Prompt](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/install-windows/install-sql-server-from-the-command-prompt?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15#AddNode) which is helpful. However, I am not able to complete the installation without error.
This is code I wrote, with the help of the link above.

```
.\Setup.exe /QS /Action=AddNode /IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS=true
/INSTANCENAME=SQL2019 /FAILOVERCLUSTERNETWORKNAME=YouClusterName
/FAILOVERCLUSTERIPADDRESSES=192.168.2.36 /CONFIRMIPDEPENDENCYCHANGE=0 
/AGTSVCACCOUNT=domainName\sqlagent /AGTSVCPASSWORD=******** 
/SQLSVCACCOUNT=domainName\sqlengine /SQLSVCPASSWORD=******** 
/PID=22222-00000-00000-00000-00000
```

This is the error I receive when it is "**Running Rules for Feature Installation**"

> The following error occurred:   You have selected a feature that is
>   not supported for Windows Server Core. The supported features on
>   Windows Server Core are: Database Engine Services, SQL Server
>   Replication, Full-Text and Semantix Extractions for Search, Analysis
>   Services, Client Tools Connectivity, Integration Services, and SQL
>   Client Connectivity SDK.
>
> Error result: -2067922334
>   Result facility code: 1214
>   Result error code: 61

Any assistance on this would be great.

I found this on the error above. However, it is for 2012, not 2019: [You cannot install a SQL Server 2012 Cluster Instance](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2727221/fix-you-cannot-install-a-sql-server-2012-cluster-instance-on-a-server)

I went through the installation process on a test server, to see what Features it picks up on, during the installation. And on the 
Cluster Node Configuration - Page.

```
Features = SQLEngine, SQLEngine\Replication, SQLEngine\FullText, SQLEngine\DQ
```

It has the features being installed that Core requires, and nothing more.
So, why is it yelling, **You have selected a feature that is not supported for Windows Server Core** ???

Comment: It sounds like a sub feature that requires a GUI is trying to be installed. That would invalidate the core installation you might want to ask this on a Microsoft Forum because it's particular to them.

Comment: Someone on the SQL Server Forum posted that this is causing the issue, that it is not allowed in the core. SQLEngine\DQ --- However, I had read that it is allowed, so I am not entirely certain on rather his information is accurate or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have the install option of **SQLEngine\DQ**
It is not allowed in Core installs of SQL Server.
Once this was removed, the installation completed without an issue.